# Format DataTable

Tags: c#, html, datatable

I am trying to format my datatable so that all the columns line up correctly.  The issue is that since each cell contains different lengths in characters, each cell has more or less than what I would like it to have. Is there an easy way to format a dataTable cell? The following code is what I have to create the table:

```
public static void ErrorLog(OdbcConnection connection, string filepath)
    {
        int ID = 0;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        XDocument theFile = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\bob\\Documents\\UpdateW5.xml");

        DataTable theTable = new DataTable("Error Log");
        //Set the report filename
        string filename = @"ErrorLog.html";
        //Check to see if directory exists, if not create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(filepath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
        //Open file for output
        TextWriter webPage = new StreamWriter(filepath + filename, false);

        //Page header
        webPage.WriteLine("<html>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<head>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<title>ErrorLog</title");
        webPage.WriteLine("</head>");

        //Page body
        webPage.WriteLine("<body>");

        //Start an output table
        webPage.WriteLine("<h1>ErrorLog</h1>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<table border=1>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<tr>"); //header row of table
        webPage.WriteLine("<th>ERROR ID</th>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<th>ITEM ID</th>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<th>DATE/TIME</th>");
        webPage.WriteLine("<th>DESCRIPTION</th>");

        foreach (XElement el in theFile.Root.Elements())
        {
            //If the node item is called ADD run the following code
            if (el.Name == "ADD")
            {
                //Check if each attribute has a value
                if (el.Attribute("invent_id") != null && el.Attribute("item_id") != null && el.Attribute("itemsize") != null && el.Attribute("color") != null && el.Attribute("curr_price") != null && el.Attribute("qoh") != null)
                {
                    Item.Item_ID = Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("item_id").Value);
                    Item.Invent_id = Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("invent_id").Value);
                    Item.Itemsize = el.Attribute("itemsize").Value;
                    Item.Color = el.Attribute("color").Value;
                    Item.Curr_price = Convert.ToDecimal(el.Attribute("curr_price").Value);
                    Item.Qoh = Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("qoh").Value);

                    if (Item.Qoh < 1)
                    {
                        webPage.WriteLine("<table border=1>");
                        webPage.WriteLine("<col align = justify>");
                        webPage.WriteLine("<tr>"); //header row of table
                        webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + ID++ + "</td>");
                        webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + now + "</td>");
                        webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + Item.Item_ID + "</td>");
                        webPage.WriteLine("<td> not added: The quantity must be positive</td>");
                    }
                    //If the quantity is above 1, then run the queries
                    else
                    {
                        //Check to make sure the item is not already in the database
                        connection.Open();
                        OdbcCommand Command1 = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE invent_id = '" + Item.Invent_id + "'", connection);
                        {
                            //If it is in the database, error out
                            OdbcDataReader reader = Command1.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                webPage.WriteLine("<table border=1>");
                                webPage.WriteLine("<tr>"); //header row of table
                                webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + ID++ + "</td>");
                                webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + now + "</td>");
                                webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + Item.Item_ID + "</td>");
                                webPage.WriteLine("<td> already in database.</td>");
                            }
                            //If it is not in the database, add the item into the table
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Item {0} ", el.Attribute("item_id").Value + " was successfully added.");
                                Console.ReadLine();

                                OdbcCommand Command2 = new OdbcCommand("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/abechtold/Documents/Update.xml' INTO TABLE item ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ADD>'", connection);
                                connection.Open();
                                OdbcDataReader reader2 = Command1.ExecuteReader();
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                            reader.Dispose();
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
                //Check if the invent id is empty, if so, do not run any of the code for ADD
                else if (el.Attribute("invent_id") == null)
                {
                    Item.Item_ID = Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("item_id").Value);

                    webPage.WriteLine("<table border=1>");
                    webPage.WriteLine("<tr>"); //header row of table
                    webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + ID++ + "</td>");
                    webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + now + "</td>");
                    webPage.WriteLine("<td>" + Item.Item_ID + "</td>");
                    webPage.WriteLine("<td> not added: An input value was an improper datatype</td>");
                }
            }
        }
        webPage.WriteLine("</table>");  //end table
        webPage.WriteLine("</body>");
        webPage.WriteLine("</html>");

        webPage.Flush();//Make sure all characters are in the file and not buffered.
        webPage.Close();//Closes the file and officially writes it to disk.
    }
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using a GridView?

Comment: Your columns don't line up? You mean because you have nested tables? You might want a different approach to the UI.

Comment: I looked into GridView a bit, and was not sure if this would be the correct route to simply paste code into HTML.

Comment: My other thought was trying to figure out how to create 1 table for my entire "Add" method.  But unsure where to start.  Was hoping this would be my last resort

Answer (score 1):

Crowcoder's comment helped me answer my question.  Since I had

```
webPage.WriteLine("<table border=1>");
```

written in every if, else statement, it was creating its own row of a table.  By removing this line from every statement, and keeping just 1 in the "Start an output table" spot.  This made it so my columns line up and provide correct spacing.